# Trying to add like functionality to my Photo Resource using Tastypie

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I have a website where people can like photographs. So I created a PhotoResource and a PhotoLikeResource (code below). I am able add a like for the photo, but I also want to return the number of total likes for a photo and whether the current user likes it already. I tried returning the information in the hydrate function (commented out in the code, but that broke the api calls). How can I accomplish this?

```
class PhotoResource(ModelResource):
tags = fields.ManyToManyField(TagResource, 'tags', null=True, blank=True)
primary_image = fields.ForeignKey(ImageResource, 'primary_image', null=True, blank=True, full=True)
user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

class Meta:
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'photos'
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
    filtering = {
        'primary_image': ALL,
        'featured': ALL
    }

# THE DEHYRDATE BELOW BREAKS THE photo_like CALL
# def dehydrate(self, bundle):
#     num_likes = PhotoLike.objects.filter(photo=bundle.obj).count()
#     bundle.data['num_likes'] = num_likes
#     user_like = PhotoLike.objects.filter(user=bundle.request.user, photo = bundle.obj).exists()
#     bundle.data['user_like'] = user_like
#     return bundle.data


class PhotoLikeResource(ModelResource):
photo = fields.ForeignKey(PhotoResource, 'photo', null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = PhotoLike.objects.all()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    resource_name = 'photo_like'
    always_return_data = True

def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    return super(PhotoLikeResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=bundle.request.user)
```

Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `return bundle` and not `return bundle.data`.

It's also good to post your traceback.